# Fonts in website not showing up correctly on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, fonts, web

I'm building my first website from scratch and in the meantime, I would like to have a "Work in progress" page. The page works correctly on Desktop and Android devices, but the font is displayed in a weird way on iOS devices, a little bit shrunk vertically and doubled. 
My css looks like this right now and I can't figure out what's the problem.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'montserratregular';
src: url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.otf') format('opentype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Not even all of these should be necessary, since I think that ttf and woff (eventually wof2) should be enough.

EDIT: 
Screenshot for reference:
[image]

Comment: iOS version? Maybe you need an SVG font. Try fontsquirrel to generate a webfont package

Comment: @lumio Tried on both iOS 8, 10 and 11 and both Safari and Chrome. I've already tried fontquirrel, in fact that's what generated the font-face that you see in the snippet above.